Computing the smallest zero of a function
I have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is positive on $(-\infty, a)$ and on $(b,\infty)$ for some known values $a$ and $b$. I want to write a software function that computes the smallest zero of $f$, if it has one, or reports that there are no zeros (i.e. that $f$ is positive everywhere). Please note that here “smallest” means closest to $-\infty$, not closest to zero.
I have a software function that computes $f(x)$ for any given value of $x$, but usually there is no closed-form formula for $f(x)$. What kind of function is $f$? We can assume that it’s continuous and has only finitely many zeros. If it helps, maybe we could assume that it’s Lipschitz. It’s typically differentiable except at some finite number of points. We certainly can’t assume that it’s a polynomial. If there are other conditions that might be helpful, please feel free to suggest them.
The obvious answer is to use the secant method, or Newton-Raphson with approximated (finite difference) derivatives. But if I start iterating at $x=a$, there is some danger that I’ll skip over the smallest root and end up at some other one. So, looking for a method that avoids this possible skipping.

This is quite broad.  I doubt there is any useful method that works for everything one can dream up. If you have a root, produced by whatever means, then at least the problem of finding the least root is confined to a known region.  Simple numerical methods (like evaluating on finer and finer meshes, looking for sign changes) might suffices.  But if each computation is expensive, this is unlikely to be a practical solution.

The last sentence of the second paragraph is an invitation to make the problem less broad, if you want to.

"evaluating on finer and finer meshes" is just bisection, isn't it? My intuition says that there must be something better than that.

Even , if we can assume that the function is continous , I share lulu's doubt that there is a method well working for all cases. Some functions heavily oscillate , in this case , we might run into trouble. The class of functions any given algorithm will work is probably quite restricted.

Doesn't my "only finitely many zeros" condition eliminate concerns about functions that oscillate heavily? I actually don't care about those kinds of functions. If my condition doesn't eliminate them, can you suggest one that will?

There is a method called Ramanujan's method that finds the smallest root of a polynomial [not necessarily function]. Check this.

@M.Riyan. Thank you. I occasionally know that my function is a polynomial, so Ramanujan’s method is somewhat relevant. I couldn’t find much info about it. Why does it work? What properties of the polynomial impact speed of convergence, etc.

I could not find any Wikipedia page. Check the You tube. The Book on Numerical Analysis by Howard Anton might be of some help.

@M.Riyan — I did watch the YouTube video. It doesn’t answer my questions. Even if I understood Hindi, I suspect it still wouldn’t.

Ramanujan's Method of Finding the Smallest Root of a Polynomial
Consider any polynomial $f(x)$ which has the form:
$$f(x)=1-(a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\cdots)$$
For small values of $x$ [this is why this method always produces the smallest root], we can apply a binomial expansion which leads to:
$$[1-(a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\cdots)]^{-1}=b_1+b_2x+b_3x^2+\cdots$$
Compare the coefficients of powers of $x$, that leads to:
$$
b_1=1\\
b_2=a_1=a_1b_1\\
b_3=a_1^2+a_2=a_1b_2+a_2b_1\\
\vdots\\\vdots\\
b_n=a_1b_{n-1}+a_2b_{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}b_1 \quad[n=2,3\cdots]
$$
Ramanujan expected that, if there existed more than one root, the successive convergents i.e. $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}$ will approach the smallest root of the equation $f(x)=0$. It is because, when we applied the Taylor expansion, we had considered $x$ to be as small as possible. If it had not been small enough, the L.H.S. and R.H.S. would have never coincided, rather left with a marginal amount of error. This condition actually assures that the value of $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}$ converges to the least root.
For further reference, look at this pdf. You can find more examples here, starting from page 51.

So, does it produce the root that’s closest to zero, or the root that’s closest to $-\infty$. I want the latter.

It seems to me that the method applies to any function of the form $1-s$, where $s$ is a (convergent?) series, not just to polynomials. As far as I can tell, no proof has been provided by Ramanujan or anyone else. People just observe that the iterates appear to be converging to a root, and declare victory.

There is a proof and generalization here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5092

What happens if there is a pair of complex conjugate roots that have a smaller radius than the smallest real root? This is also known as Bernoulli (shift) iteration or the power iteration for the transpose of the companion matrix (whose eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial).

As this methods converges linearly with the quotient of the two smallest roots as linear rate, one could wonder if a complete factorization with one of the superlinear methods (and then selecting from the list of roots) might be faster.

Unfortunately, it produces roots that's closest to 0. So it would probably not help.

See also here, starting on page 213: https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/4D18C84ACB6B5964C65965774D10529B/S0017089500004675a.pdf/div-class-title-chapter-2-of-ramanujan-s-second-notebook-div.pdf
